# ASP.NET User Login Controls

Tags: asp.net

Suppose that I want to display a message for anonymous users and logged in users.

1. Anonymous users show "Not logged in"
2. Logged in users show "Welcome, [username]"
3. For both users, show a login button when logged out, and a logout button when logged in.

How can i implement these features using ASP's login controls?

Comment: You can learn more about that on ASP.NET templates.

Comment: Your comment has no meaning. Remove it or be more specific

Comment: Read more [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) gentleman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using ASP.NET Membership then:

1. User.Identity.IsAuthenticated gives you true if user is logged in.
2. User.Identity.Name gives you the user name.
3. Use 1.